# Create and link a .dylib in Xcode in C

Tags: c, xcode, dylib

I'm stuck with a problem.

Well, I want to create my own dylib file, and inside of it write some methods, etc. You know, just a normal library.

Ok, so I opened Xcode, New project, and I selected Dynamic library. I've created a *main_lib.c* file, and wrote this method inside of it:

```
void printMessage(char *str){

    printf("%s", str);

}
```

Obviously, I linked this file with the .dylib file and builded the project, no errors. After this, I created another project, selected Command Line Application and created a main.c file.

I imported the builded .dylib file in this project.

I asked one friend of mine, he said that at this point I should create an header file and write inside of it the function prototype of the dylib. So I created a main_lib.h file and declared this prototype:

```
void printMessage(char *str);
```

At this point, I write in the main.c file this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main_lib.h"

int main(void){

    printMessage("just a try");

 return 0;    

}
```

But when I build this it says:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

It means that the compiler cannot find printMessage, right? But why? What am I doing wrong? Please help :) Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Did you set the `.dylib` as being a dependency of the main program?

Comment: Uhm, I checked the "required" textbox in "Build Phases", if you mean that

Comment: You need to tell Xcode that the program uses the `.dylib`.  It's in one of the high-level project setting pages.

Comment: I've found "target dipendencies" in the "Build Phases" tab, but if I try to add something it shows an empty list! I cannot add anything to it...

Answer (score 2):

To include it just add it to **Target Dependencies** and **Link With Libraries** in "Build Phases" and thats it, it should work.